# Multi-threaded ajax call for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multithreading

I am trying to make a web app that will figure out if one or many e-commerce items are out of stock from their url(s) entered by user. These urls can be seperated by commas. Currently, I make ajax calls to my one of my PHP scripts for each url after spliting them by comma in a javascript loop. Below is the code for that:

```
function sendRequest(urls) {

    if (urls.length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        var A = urls.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var result_set = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if (result_set.flag == 1) {
                        insertRow('stock-table', result_set.url, result_set.title); // It populates a table and insert row in it.
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "scrapper.php?url=" + A[i], true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
}
```

The scrapper.php goes like:

```
<?php
function get_title($data)
{
    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $data, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
    return $title;
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else if (isset($_GET["url"])) {

    $url = $_GET["url"];
    $title = null;
    $result_set = null;
    $flag = 0;
    $file = fopen($url,"r");
    if (!$file) {
        echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
        exit;
    }
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file, 1024);
        if ($title == null){
            $title = get_title($line);
        }
        if (preg_match('/<span[^>]*>Add to Cart/i',
            $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            break;
        }
        if (preg_match('/Sold Out|Out of Stock/i',
            $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);

    $result_set = array("flag" => $flag,
        "url" => $url,
        "title" => $title
    );

    echo json_encode($result_set);

}
?>
```

Now problem is: This program takes too much time even for two urls. Although, I moved from file_get_contents()(which was even slower) to here (ftp solution) . I have few confusion is my mind:

1. Considering my javascript, is it like sending one ajax call, waiting for its response and then second one?
2. If point one is not true, will scrapper.php be able to respond to second call from the loop? since it is busy with handeling first ajax call computation.
3. If point 2 is true, how can I make it multi-threaded such that ajax keeps sending the call until loop is finished and scrapper.php activates different threads for each call to then reply back to client once a thread completes its execution? (How can a make to pool of limted threads and grant new ajax response once a threads compltes its execution. Since, I have 200 urls. So, making 200 threads must not be an optimal solution)
4. Is it a good solution if I insert all urls (around 200) into the database, and then fetch all of them to make multi-threaded executions. In that case, how can i reply back multiple results from multiple threads against a single ajax call?

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. XMLHttpRequest defaults to *async*, which means every new request with said *async* will execute in parallel.
2. Completely depends on how you're running PHP. In typical setups - and it's unlikely you're doing otherwise, your http server will wait for an available PHP worker thread from a thread pool, or execute a PHP binary directly. Either way, more than one PHP program can execute at once. (Think about how a regular website works. You need to be able to support more than one user at a time.)
3. N/A
4. If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to handle all requests in one Ajax call? Just send a list of all the URLs in the request, and loop server-side. Your current way of doing it is fine. Most likely the "slow" nature can be attributed to your connection to the remote URLs.

Some other notes:

- I would validate the URL before passing it into `fopen`, especially considering the user can pass simply pass in a relative path and start reading your "private" files.
- I'd switch back to `file_get_contents`. It's pretty much equivalent to `fopen` but does much of the work for you.
- Not sure if intentional, but I'd use the newer `const` keyword instead of `var` for the XMLHttpRequest variable in the for loop's inner block. Currently, the `var` gets hoisted to the top of the function scope and you are simply overwriting it every iteration of the loop. If you want to add more logic to the XMLHttpRequest, you may find yourself prone to some unintentional behaviour.